# Boolean flags with xparse, and xparse in general

Tags: environments, xparse, optional-arguments, arguments

I would like to define an environment whose syntax works like this

```
\begin{myenv}{arg1,arg2}[opt_1,opt_2,...,opt_n]
body, taking several lines
\end{myenv}
```

One of the optional arguments is to be a numerical value, and the other optional arguments are all to be treated as boolean flags. Inside the environment's definition, I would like to use something like `\ifthenelse` to handle the various cases for these flags.

As it happens, arg1 is to be a string and will be used as an external file name, arg2 is a numerical value that will be written to a different external file, and the optional arguments are to control exactly what is written where. The body of the environment may (or may not) be written to an external file too.

It may be that the syntax above is not easily feasible. I've been looking at `xparse`, and not making much progress.

In trying to understand how `xparse` works, I've tried

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testguts}{ m m }{%
  arg1 is #1
  arg2 is #2
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{ > { \SplitArgument { 2 } { , } } m t b}{%
  \testguts #1%
  optional is #2%
  and body is #3%
  that's it%
}{nothing post}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}[option]
random body
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

But that gets an "Illegal parameter number" error. It looks like argument `#3` isn't defined? Why not?

If the reference to `#3` is eliminated (comment out that line), then the output is

```
arg1 is first arg2 is second -NoValue-optional is Γthat’s it[option] random body nothing post
```

What is going on with `\SplitArgment`? Why must its output be fed to a separate command (`\testguts`) to see the individual parts that have been parsed out?

Leaving that mystery aside, the first part of the above makese sense. It's clear where `arg1 is first arg2 is second` came from. But why is `-NoValue-optional` the next thing, and where did the `Γ` come from?

The `xparse` documentation makes it sound like `t` is to be used for an optional argument that acts as a boolean flag, exactly as I want, but I have no idea how to make it work. Ideally, it should be possible to say something like `\IfNoValueTF{keyword}{false case}{true case}', but nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: you don't want `\SplitArgument` here you want to pass the argument as-is to a key-value parser, the original `keyval` package (as used by `\includegraphics`) or (more in the spirit of using  xparse use l3keys, as both xparse and l3keys are built in to the latex format these days

Comment: I tried to make your fragment into something to see your issue but it gives `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \environment myenv code.
<to be read again> 
                   3`  If that is not what you expected, can you edit the question? If it is what you expected, as if you scrol past any error the result is essentially arbitrary there is no point on asking why any particular outcome happens.

Comment: The `t` spec takes an argument so you have `t{b}` so `#2` will be true if the command is followed by `b` and false otherwise. so `b` is not taken as a specifier for `#3`

Comment: Many thanks. I've been bashing at this for a while, and you've put me on the scent.